# How to avoid cloudformation circular reference with securitygroups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How do I avoid circular references between cloudformation templates?

E.g. I have one template with my Web Server, another with my Database Instance. Template DB will lok like:

```
"Database": {
  "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
  "Properties": {
     // lots of other props
     "VPCSecurityGroups": [ {"Ref":"DBSecurityGroup"} ]
  }
},
"DBSecurityGroup" : {
  "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    // lots of other props
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [{... "SourceSecurityGroupId":{"Ref":"WebSecurityGroup"}}]
  }
}
```

But in my Web Server template, I need to reference the DBSecurityGroup:

```
"WebServer": {
  "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
     // lots of other props
     "SecurityGroups": [ {"Ref":"DBSecurityGroup"} ]
  }
},
"WebSecurityGroup" : {
  "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    // lots of other props
    "SecurityGroupEgress": [{... "SourceSecurityGroupId":{"Ref":"DBSecurityGroup"}}]
  }
}
```

How do I avoid these circular references between templates?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress` resource, instead of a  SecurityGroupEgress property.

See a example snippet at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html#scenario-ec2-security-group-ingress

Comment: I know how to use SecurityGroupIngress separately. But I don't understand how it helps me solve the multiple templates problem? Do you mind expounding?

Comment: I am sorry, i misunderstood the question. One approach would be to have 3 templates, one "root" for the SGs that passes them as parameters to both the Web and DB templates.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the effort. I thought about that, but wanted the SecurityGroup in the same template as the server, since the logic and rules are closely tied. So I came up with a different solution. SG Tagging. It is pretty neat.

Comment: @deitch Could you offer details on the SG tagging approach you came up with? Thanks

Comment: @gliptak sorry, it has been four years, I just don't remember. I do everything nowadays in terraform, and that only for basic setup.